# Recursive SQL column sub-select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, subquery

I apologize that this question is not labeled better, I do not know how to describe without an example.  Here is what I am trying to achieve.

My Simplified Data:

```
ID  ParamName ParamValue
-----------------------
1  'Item Code'   '100'
1  'Amount'      '.99'
2  'Item Code'   '555'
2  'Amount'      '1.99'
2  'Item Code'   '200'
2  'Amount'      '2.99'
2  'Item Code'   '221'
2  'Amount'      '.89'
```

I need to write a query to return the data in 2 columns like such (if multiple values for single ID, assume that item codes and amounts match up in the order that they are in the table):

```
ItemCode    Amount
-----------------------
'100'      '.99'
'555'      '1.99'
'200'      '2.99'
'221       '.89'
```

This is the closest i can come, but when there are multiple Item Codes with the same ID I do not want to group them with Max() and Sum().  I am assuming there is some kind of recursion needed but I do not even know where to begin to research.

```
select
(Select Max(ParamValue) from EventDetail where id = base.id and ParamName = 'Item Code') as ItemCode,
(Select Sum(ParamValue) from EventDetail where id = base.id and ParamName = 'Amount') as Amount
from 
(
  select distinct id from EventDetail
) base
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09b773/1/0

Thank you for viewing!

Comment: There currently doesn't seem to be a way to understand that row 3 goes with row 4, row 5 goes with row 6, etc. Is there any other column in the table? If not, I don't know that this is solvable in a predictable and deterministic way - things like adding an index can change the way SQL Server will determine how to order these rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not another column that would link the rows together.  At this time I must make the assumption that they were inserted sequentially (trust me I do not like this either).  You are correct, an index change could completely screw this up.

Comment: You need to fix the data model, sorry, or transpose this information on the client, making the same assumption that the order the rows are retrieved will not change. There isn't a way to express what you want in a relational way - a table is an unordered bag of rows, by definition. You cannot make any assumptions about "inserted sequentially" - this is not how a relational database works (but you may get away with it in toys like Access).

Comment: @koolaide - don't ignore Aaron and I -- this solution will not work, you will start to see "strange" results at some point in the future.

Comment: Hah! Good catch thank you, they did indeed change my data.  Removing it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first take the simple case that there is some way to group Item Codes and Item amounts that go together.

So the data would look like this:

```
ID  ParamName ParamValue
-----------------------
1  'Item Code'   '100'
1  'Amount'      '.99'
2  'Item Code'   '555'
2  'Amount'      '1.99'
3  'Item Code'   '200'
3  'Amount'      '2.99'
4  'Item Code'   '221'
4  'Amount'      '.89'


WITH uniqueRowID AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT ID
   FROM myTable
)
SELECT uniqueRowID, Item.ParamValue as Item, Amount.ParamValue as Amount
FROM uniqueRowID
JOIN myTable as Item ON uniqueRowID.ID = Item.ID AND Item.ParamName='Item Code'
JOIN myTable as Amount ON uniqueRowID.ID = Amount.ID AND Amount.ParamName='Amount'
```

Now in your case, you need to have some way to order the items -- you might need to add this to your table -- I'm going to call this column myOrder

To get a grouping as above we then do the following:

```
WITH item AS
(
   SELECT ParamValue,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myOrder) as rn
   FROM myTable 
   WHERE ParamName = 'Item Code'
), amount AS
(
   SELECT ParamValue,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myOrder) as rn
   FROM myTable 
   WHERE ParamName = 'Amount'
)
SELECT item.ParamValue as ItemCode, amount.ParamValue as Amount
FROM item
JOIN amount ON item.rn = amount.rn
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yeah I saw that and improved my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I did overlook an "InsertedDate" column. I believe this will work for the sorting.

Comment: @koolaide it took half an hour to spot that other column? Next time, please give the schema of your table, instead of just the columns you assume might be relevant.